# binding jquery onclick even to this tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [great tooltip](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easytooltip/03.html) which displays the tooltip (title of an anchor element with .tooltip function called on it) upon hover. This time around, I want it to display upon click so I did this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".icons a.tooltips").click(function() {
        return $($(this).attr("href")).html().easyTooltip();

        // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

the html for this is as follows:

```
<div class="foo">
    <a class="bar" title="Lorem ipsum" href="#"></a>
    <a class="bar" title="meaningless text" href="#"></a>
    <a class="bar" title="more meaningless text" href="#"></a>
    <a class="bar" title="even more meaningless text" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code from the link is totally different from the one you are posting. Why arent you doing like it is described in the link?

Comment: I think it's the initializing code for the plugin. The normal one in the script is :-
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".icons a.tooltips").easyTooltip();

        });
Please download the plugin to understand what I mean

Comment: meaning I try and achieve the onclick even from the plugin file itself?

Comment: Yes, wrap the original code in a .click event... Havent tried it though

Comment: I tried that initially but it failed to work:(

Comment: @Santy - Check out my answer as well. May just be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, easyTooltip uses the hover event to determine whether to show or hide a tooltip. This behavior can be changed only via the source of the plugin. Fortunately, that turns out to be quite straight forward as you'll be able to see in the demo below. What I've done is basically change the tooltip trigger from hover to click, while keeping the rest of the behavior (and code) exactly the same as before.

In the demo, the plugin code is embedded as well. Please note the comments i've added to point out the changes in plugin code.

**Updated demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/FhLLA/2/

Comment: +1 to modify the plugin source code. But notice what happens when you click multiple times on a link. (But i know you don't have to do all of the work ;) )

Comment: @ThdK - Oh! I didn't see that.. will need a little more code to prevent that behavior i guess.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to ensure the tooltip element is created only once.

Answer (score 1):

The easytooltip function is only needed to initiate the tooltips. You only have to call this function once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("foo a.bar").easyTooltip();
});
```

This will show the tooltip on mouse over.

If you want to change it to fire only on click, you'll have to modify the script of this plugin or find another one.

Example jquery plugin that will allow you to specify a jquery event to show your tooltip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show